# Perforce Globally Locked Items after failed/aborted Submit operation (push)

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-stream

I am new to Perforce so please help me out. I am working on a folder on the Perforce GUI and I was able to do my work smoothly until this one incident. I had submitted a changelist with the folder contents for a Swarm review and it was approved.

Then, once everything was A-okay from my side as well, I clicked on Submit and as it was being submitted, I clicked on 'Stop' by mistake and it stopped. The problem starts from there. I have some files now that are apparently 'shelved' and the files in my changelist have a red lock icon, indicating that I have globally locked it. I try unshelving the files, but it says there are no files to unshelve. I try unlocking the files in the changelist but this also not possible. The files are globally locked in the depot as well.

I would move on from here but now I can't checkout any other file from my workspace and it's like I'm locked out from my file system. I have read-only access to files and folders I haven't checked out and I can only edit checked out files. I cannot rename or move my checked-out files either.

I tried unlocking and unshelving from the command line as well but to no avail. I have tried the

```
p4 -g -c workspace_name unlock -c changelist_number
```

but it says `-g` is not a valid argument (I read in the documentation that it is the global argument in the unlock process). Additionally, when I remove the `-g` argument and run the above line, the command line just stays in that state and doesn't return anything till I stop it (Ctrl+C).

**Edit:** I forgot to add that when I tried adding the `-g` argument after the command `unlock` (before or after the `-c changelist`), it gave me the error:

```
Usage: -c client unlock [-f] -r
       or
       unlock [ -f ] [-c | -s changelist# | -x ] [files...]
Invalid option: -g.
```

Comment: The `-g` flag should go after the `unlock` (it's an arg to the server's `unlock` command, whereas `-c client` is an arg to `p4` telling it what client name to use when it connects to the server to run `unlock`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to add that when I tried adding the `-g` argument after the command `unlock`, it gave me an error.

Comment: Have your admin run `p4 lockstat -c your_workspace`.  Sounds like it might be stuck in a bad state (the admin should be able to fix that, and may want to follow up with Perforce support since this shouldn't happen).  The admin may also be able to use `p4 unlock -f` to unlock the files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! For some reason, it unlocked itself after the weekend. My colleagues mentioned that P4V is laggy but for days on end, it was frustrating and causing panic in me 